# Cmake wildcard for External Project

Tags: cmake

I want to pass some settings to an External Project via a ProjectSettings.cmake file. I know I can use the `CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE` for this purpose (passed via `CMAKE_ARGS` to the `ExternalProject_add()`).

But I have to do this for many external projects that my main project builds and do not want to keep repeating it - I have a generic variable defined for `CMAKE_ARGS` that is presently passed to every call of `ExternalProject_Add()` and I want to just append to this.

Is there a wildcard mechanism for the `PROJECT-NAME` field of this `CMAKE_PROJECT_<PROJECT-NAME>_INCLUDE`?

Or is there a way by which I can make the CMakeLists.txt of all the external projects I want to build include my ProjectSettings.cmake? Note that I do not have access to change all of them - hence the need to manipulate them from the parent project.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping reoccurring code centrally is one of the major purposes of [CMake macros](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/macro.html) and [functions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html).

So in your case this would look something like this:

```perl
macro(My_ExternalProject_Add _name)
    ExternalProject_Add(
        ${_name}
        CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_PROJECT_${_name}_INCLUDE:FILEPATH=ProjectSettings.cmake
        ${ARGN}
    )
endmacro()
```

The `ARGN` will add all parameters given after `_name`. So just place the `macro()` in your root `CMakeLists.txt` file and replace all `ExternalProject_Add()` calls with `My_ExternalProject_Add()`.

Alternatively you could use `CMAKE_ARGS -C ProjectSettings.cmake` [initial cache command line option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options) to pre-load settings for an external project (then you won't need the project's name).

**References**

- [Function vs. Macro in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297999/function-vs-macro-in-cmake)
- [How to define a cmake macro in a sub_directory that uses the CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42759610/how-to-define-a-cmake-macro-in-a-sub-directory-that-uses-the-current-source-dir)
- [How to store CMake build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588517/how-to-store-cmake-build-settings)

Comment: @GaneshSathyanarayanan Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer - or any other one - solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: If wrapping would be a central purpose of cmake, then cmake would support better argument quoting. Everyone develops their own tiny little puny language and then cannot even forward argument lists to sub-calls where arguments may be empty...